# Questions about -ig- and indirect and direct objects

Tags: translation, affixes

I am sort of confused about la suffix *-ig-*, and how it would be used in translating this sentence:

> For example, let's say there is a political advisor, and they go to a candidate and say "I will make them elect you," meaning that they will make the people elect the candidate.

This sentence is a little hard for me to translate though, here are some possible translations:

> Mi igos ilin elekti vin

> Mi igos al ili elekti vin

> Mi elektigos ilin al vi

> Mi elektigos vin al ili

Which one of these best tranlates "I will make them elect you"? Which one is ambiguos?

Comment: PS The reason I am confused is that I don't know, given Esperanto's word order flexibility, which gets accross the right meaning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Mi igos ilin elekti vin
```

Plej simpla. Tio ĉiam funkcios ĉar ĉiu objekto sekvas la koncernan verbon. Ne eblas miskompreni tiun ĉi.

```
Mi igos al ili elekti vin
```

Tiu aspektas malĝuste, ĉar `igi` postulas objekton rektan. [Jen klarigo](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/gravaj_verboj/igi.html) pri la funkciado de `igi`.

```
Mi elektigos ilin al vi
```

Tiu frazo povus funkcii. Kiam la verbo normale havus rektan objekton, ekzemple `manĝi karotojn`, kaj oni aldone uzas `-ig-`, la objekton de `igi` oni enkondukas per `al`. Ekzemple: `mi manĝigas karotojn al la kunikloj` (tio povus esti `mi igas la kuniklojn manĝi karotojn`).

Tamen, notu ke en tiu ĉi frazo, vi elektas ilin, kaj ne inverse, kiel vi volis, ke ili elektu vin.

```
Mi elektigos vin al ili
```

Tiu ĉi bonas. La *igata* objekto estas tiu, kiu venas post `al`. Do tio ĉi signifus: `mi igos ilin elekti vin`. Vi trovos pli da informo pri `-ig-` kun agaj radikoj (`elekt-` ĉi okaze) [ĉi tie](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/vortfarado/afiksoj/sufiksoj/ig.html#i-g6g).

Comment: “La igata objekto estas tiu, kiu venas post al” Bonege!! Dankon! Sed pensas ankaux mi, ke “Mi igos ilin elekti vin” estas plej simpla :-)